# Why does my SQL Alchemy (CORE) join object lose its join condition when queried

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Relative SQL Alchemy newbie here. I create an outer join object and then use it in a select query. While the query is created, the join condition disappears, resulting in a cartesian product.

Creating the join:

```
data_set = join(db.client, db.employee, isouter=True)
```

Debugger shows the value of the join object as:

> data_set = client LEFT OUTER JOIN employee ON employee.id =
>   client.account_manager_id

Query the join:

```
qry = select([data_set.c.client_id.label('ID'), data_set.c.client_contract_client_name.label('CONTRACT CLIENT'),
                  data_set.c.client_project_client_name.label('PROJECT CLIENT'),
                  data_set.c.client_ins_dt.label('INSERT'), data_set.c.client_update_dt.label('UPDATE'),
                  (data_set.c.employee_last_name + data_set.c.employee_first_name).label('ACCT MGR')]).\
        order_by(data_set.c.client_contract_client_name)
```

Debugger shows the SQL of qry as:

> SELECT client.id AS "ID", client.contract_client_name AS "CONTRACT
>   CLIENT", client.project_client_name AS "PROJECT CLIENT", client.ins_dt
>   AS "INSERT", client.update_dt AS "UPDATE", employee.last_name ||
>   employee.first_name AS "ACCT MGR"
>   FROM client, employee ORDER BY
>   client.contract_client_name

Notice the FROM clause. Where did my JOIN go?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out! I needed to use the select_from() method of the select command. My new (correctly functioning) query appears as follows...

```
qry = select([data_set.c.client_id.label('ID'), data_set.c.client_contract_client_name.label('CONTRACT CLIENT'),
                  data_set.c.client_project_client_name.label('PROJECT CLIENT'),
                  data_set.c.client_ins_dt.label('INSERT'), data_set.c.client_update_dt.label('UPDATE'),
                  (data_set.c.employee_last_name + data_set.c.employee_first_name).label('ACCT MGR')]).\
        select_from(data_set).\
        order_by(data_set.c.client_contract_client_name)
```

Notice the second line from the bottom - select_from(data_set)